# Fix animated GIF images which eog can't open, but Firefox and ImageMagick can

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, eog, gif, convert-command

I received a collection of animated GIF images from a friend, but I am unable to open some of them them with the standard image viewer `eog`.

The error messages showing up when trying to open them include:

- > GIF image loader cannot understand this image
- > Circular table entry in GIF file
- > Stack overflow

However, **the images are not corrupt**, because I can open them with Firefox without problems, also with the ImageMagick viewer, which does not play the animation automatically though.

Examining the GIFs with `file` returns the output below, both for the images I can and cannot open (varying sizes though):

```
GIF image data, version 89a, 400 x 300
```

I want to be able to open all these images in `eog`. Can I somehow "fix" the "broken" images to make them readable for the standard image viewer, e.g. by using ImageMagick's conversion abilities to turn them into something else and back?

Comment: Maybe try opening it in `gimp` or any other image editor and save it again from there, maybe this will fix things.

Answer (score 4):

Usually when some program can't open certain GIFs it's because of optimization used for this image.

You can try running ImageMagick with the `-coalesce` option. This will redraw each frame with all the details from previous frames. This will increase file size, but undo complex frame optimizations.

```
convert original.gif -coalesce unoptimized.gif
```

If this doesn't help, please provide a sample GIF with this problem.

Comment: Works for me! +1